# Not able to extract full blocks of text matching some strings across multiple lines if strings can be present one or more times

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract blocks of information from a text file to be able to reprocess them later.
The block I need to find and extract looks like this:

```
Group NAME

Description DESCRIPTION

Group member MEMBER
```

There are no groups without members and the description is not always present.

Members of the group, however, can be one or more. Member name can be a name, but also a number.

I've tried to make a Perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $path="input.txt";

open my $fh, "<", $path or die "Can't open $path: $!";
#local $/;
my $accumulated_text = '';
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    $accumulated_text .= $line;
    #Match against accumulated text
    if ($accumulated_text =~ /group.*\s*(description.*\s*)?\s*(member.*\s*)+/)
 {
        say $&;
        $accumulated_text = '';
    }
}
close $fh;
```

But it only returns one group member and not all others (if any).
If I try to use '{1,}' instead of '+' I get the same result and if I use '{2,}' or any other number, it returns that exact number, but no more.
How can I do to extract the whole block with all group members?

Desired output is:

```
Group GROUP_NAME
Member MEMBER_1
Member MEMBER_2
Member MEMBER_3
Member MEMBER_4
......
```

Or

```
Group GROUP_NAME
Description DESCRIPTION
Member MEMBER_1
Member MEMBER_2
Member MEMBER_3
Member MEMBER_4
......
```

But I always get:

```
Group GROUP_NAME
Member MEMBER_1
```

or

```
Group GROUP_NAME
Description DESCRIPTION
Member MEMBER_1
```

No more than one member...
How can I handle more than one group member?

Thank you

Comment: This code accumulates the text line by line, and as soon as it finds a single member the regular expression matches, and  it stops adding the rest of the text to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Process line by line and identify the beginning of a new group by a line starting with `Group`  which is not followed by `member`.  Then store lines for each group separately

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd);  # or use core Data::Dumper

my @groups;

while (my $line = <>) { 
    chomp $line;

    if ($line =~ /^\s*Group\s+(?!member)/) { 
        # Start collecting lines for a new group
        push @groups, [$line];
    }   
    else { 
        push @{$groups[-1]}, $line; 
    }   
}

dd \@groups;
```

The [diamond operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators)  `<>` reads line by line file(s) with names given on the command-line, so run this as `perl progname filename` (or `progname filename` if it is made executable).

The `(?!member)` is a negative [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), which "asserts" -- only "looks," without advancing the engine and consuming characters -- that `member` is not right next ahead of that position.

The anonymous arrays with group's lines are stored as elements of an array here. It also makes sense to store them in a hash, perhaps with the key being the group's name, depending on how this is used.  That should be a simple modification.

---

In the above I forgot that you want to store only parts of lines other than the group heading. It is easy to edit the obtained arrays but there is also another, simpler, way to do this: first break up the line and then test parts.

If the exact amount of whitespace between words doesn't matter break the line as

```
my ($first, $second, @rest) = split ' ', $line;

if ($first eq 'Group' and $second ne 'member') {
    # Start collecting lines for a new group
    push @groups, [$line];
}
elsif ($first ne 'Group') {
    push @{$groups[-1]}, $line;
}
else {
    push @{$groups[-1]}, join ' ', $second, @rest;
}
```

That `' '` in `split` is a special pattern, equivalent to `/\s+/` except that leading and trailing spaces are discarded.

If the spaces do matter for some reason, one way to keep them is with a regex

```
while (<>) { 
    chomp;

    my @parts = /(\S+)(\s*)/g;  # drops possible leading space

    next if @parts < 3;  # just one word (and perhaps space) on the line?

    if ($parts[0] eq 'Group' and $parts[2] ne 'member') { 
        # Start collecting lines for a new group
        push @groups, [$_];
    }   
    elsif ($parts[0] ne 'Group') {
        push @{$groups[-1]}, $_;
    }
    else {
        push @{$groups[-1]}, join '', @parts[1..$#parts];
    }   
}
```

If the `member` field can actually have more characters following then use `$parts[2] !~ /^member/` instead of `ne`.

We can keep spaces with [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)-ing as well (by capturing the separator pattern, `split /(\s+)/`) but then we need to clean up the leading spaces since they are preserved as well, what is a little messy and brings in the regex anyway.

Comment: @mmurro  Fyi, edited considerably since posting